# ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am running the quickstart.py example code under 
[Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/python) and I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.

I created a `credentials.json` file with project owner rights.

The error occurs in the following piece of code:

```
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server()
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

I notice also that the token.pickle file is not being created. This is the error output:

```
  File "updateSlidev01.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "updateSlidev01.py", line 31, in main
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 174, in from_client_secrets_file
    return cls.from_client_config(client_config, scopes=scopes, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 147, in from_client_config
    'Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.')
ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.
```

Comment: How did you create that credentials.json file?

Comment: Hi! That was exactly the problem. I answered the question below. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the json generated under Service account keys Manage service accounts and not the one under OAuth 2.0 client IDs.

Follow this instructor for creating oauth client id. https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#oauth-client-id

Comment: What can you use instead if the json was created as a service account?

Comment: Found the solution for it here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

Comment: @Kajsa Thanks for that, always appreciate it when someone comes back to answer their question.

Comment: Hi - so can I ask does this mean a normal serivce account cannot be used for such an app?

Answer (score 64):

For anyone coming here because they would like to actually connect to the GCP calendar API via a service-account and not this Oauth2 client id, create the `creds` object in the original example as follows:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

Assuming the service-account is configured with the correct access, this will access the calendar without prompting user for confirmation.

Comment: god bless you 

Comment: Why would we use a scope of "sqlservice.admin" if we're trying to connect to the GCP calendar API? I think you meant "calendar.readonly." Please correct if I'm right.

Comment: Probably - I think this was just the scope I happened to be using at the time.  But yes, obviously use the appropriate scope for the task at hand.

Comment: You can find the source url for service account delegation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests

Answer (score 1):

In my case `credentials.json` file had wrong keys names.

File looked like this:

```
{"SCc":{"client_id":"****","project_id":"****","wnc":"****","dVc":"****","vnc":"****","p2a":"****","kNc":["http://localhost"]}}
```

I changed it to:

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"****","project_id":"****","auth_uri":"****","token_uri":"****","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"****","client_secret":"****","redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]}}
```

And works fine.

Comment: Thank you! I was having the exact same problem. Fixing the keys in this way fixes things. But such a bizarre issue

Comment: I also had the same issue.