# Google Drive API Errors, despite enabled API with secret client files from Service Account and OAuth 2.0 Client ID

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am simply trying to create a new folder on google drive using the `Google Drive API`.

I have created a `Service Account` as well as a `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` (and have downloaded their respective client secret `.json` files) for a project in which the Drive API has been enabled.

However, I am still encountering endless problems.  The [template example below](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#python) has not worked for me (nor have any other solutions to people encountering the same problem).

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Invoices',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
}
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

If I am using:

`SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']`

`credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPE)`

then plugging in the `.json` downloaded from the Service Account for `CLIENT_SECRET_FILE`, I get the error `Client secrets must be for a web or installed app`

If I instead try to authenticate `CLIENT_SECRET_FILE` with a key json file generated via OAuth2 credentials I get and `Authorization Error`

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client...
```

I have also created an `API Key` for the project.  Is there an easier way to achieve this by using the API Key, as opposed to the .json files?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating the authorization part? Have you checked this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509140/11772035)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that solution which also failed. I stubbornly kept adding the denied redirect URIs to my list of authorized redirects and after adding the 5th it all started magically working.  Not sure why nor how long it will last...

Comment: Would you mind posting it as an answer (for documentation purposes)?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the redirect URIs needed into the list.