# Google SheetsAPI: ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

Very similar to this question: [ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56445257/valueerror-client-secrets-must-be-for-a-web-or-installed-app) but with a twist: I'm trying to do this through a Google Cloud Virtual Machine.

Recently, the Out-Of-Band (OOB) flow stopped working for me (it seems the reason may lie here: [oob-migration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration). Until then, I was able to easily run the Google Sheets API on the Virtual Machine **to both read/write on Google Sheet files**

Now, I'm trying to follow this [Python quickstart for google sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) which is almost identical to the code I already had, under the `"Configure the sample"` section.

My code on Python right now is:

```
        scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
        creds = None       
        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', scopes)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    credentials_path, scopes)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())
        #Store creds in object
        my_creds = creds
        #Create service
        build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=my_creds)
```

But every time Ì get this error:

> `ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.`

For the record, I did create the credentials under `"OAuth 2.0 Client IDs"` on Google Cloud, and the application type is `"Web application"`. If that's not the type, I don't know which one it should be.

Thank you so much for your help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are are using was designed for an installed. Which is exactly what your error message is saying.   The QuickStart clearly states `Click Application type > Desktop app`.

While i agree the error message states installed or web, i am not sure that code can be used for a web application.

> Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.

Open the file denoted by credentials_path the file should have the following format.

credentials.json

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "[redacted]",
    "project_id": "daimto-tutorials-101",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "[redacted]",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

Points to check.

1. it must say "installed"
2. redirect_uris must not include anything like `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`

Here is a of video which will show you how to create the proper credentials file for use with that code.  This should be done though [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

- [How to create Google Oauth2 installed application credentials.json](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ)

Note: I highly doubt that this issue is due to oob, you would have a different error message if it was.

## update Web app works.

I was able to test this with using a web app credentials. the only change i had to make was to denote the port i wanted the code to run on in order to get a static port I needed to add a redirect uri to the developer console project.

I made no other changes to the standard quickstart.

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=53911)
```