# Credentials object from google service-account has no attribute `to_json`

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

In official [google python client library docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python#configure_the_sample) it is suggested to create credentials using Oauth2 client id:

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

and save them using `to_json`:

```
token.write(creds.to_json())
```

But if I try to use service-account credentials as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509140/7225171) or in [the following doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) like this:

```
creds2 = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, SCOPES)
```

The types of **`creds2`** and **`creds`** are different, and **`creds2`** (from service_account) does not have `to_json` function. It does not even have `items()`, so I can not call `json.dumps({k: v for (k, v) in creds.items()})` directly.

How can this type of credentials be saved into json file?

Libs versions:

```
google-api-python-client==2.84.0
google-auth==2.17.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service accounts don't need to store user credentials just let it run authorization when needed the client library will handle everything for you

Comment: Is there a document confirming this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#overview