# Google Drive v3 API: Get Shared Drive 404 but List Drives Works

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, google-client

So, I have the below code to get a specific Google Shared Drive by its id:

```
import os.path

from google.oauth2 import service_account # see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509140/497745 and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "credentials.json"

def main():

  creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)        

  try:
        drive_api_service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)

        # see: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/drive_v3.drives.html#get
        folder = (drive_api_service.drives()
          .get(driveId="1AEZqVMFTv9qTVp7QVA", useDomainAdminAccess=True)  
          .execute())

  except Exception as error:
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

*Note:* For security reasons, I've manually changed the drive ID. But I know the ID is valid because I'm getting it from the result of successfully calling: `drive_api_service.drives().list().execute()` with the same service account.

My service account is in a different Google Cloud account than the Google Workspace with the Shared Drive.

However, I've:

1. Added my service account for Domain Wide Delegation.
2. Added my service account, via its email address, as a `Content Manager` to the shared drive.
3. I've turned on "Allow users outside XXX to access files in shared drives"

The shared drive has no folders.

My service account is able to `list` the shared drive with no problems.

```
{'kind': 'drive#driveList', 'drives': [{'id': '1AEZqVMFTv9qTVp7QVA', 'name': 'dcf_results', 'kind': 'drive#drive'}]}
```

However, when I try to `get` the drive with the above code, I get a 404.

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives/0ADQqULDEv5pYUk9PVA?useDomainAdminAccess=true&alt=json returned "Shared drive not found: 0ADQqULDEv5pYUk9PVA". Details: "[{'message': 'Shared drive not found: 1AEZqVMFTv9qTVp7QVA', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'driveId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
```

I've noticed that I've had to jump through a ton of obscure hoops to make sure the service account has all of the settings ticked, and access added to even get to where I could list the shared drive via my service account in the external Google Workspace account.

So, my guess is:

1. There is some obscure setting or permission I've missed that allows the service account to do more than list Shared Drives in the external Google Workspace
2. I'm making the `get` call incorrectly. Maybe I can't get a shared drive directly by its Id, only a folder under that shared drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current situation, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about removing `useDomainAdminAccess=True` from `folder = (drive_api_service.drives().get(driveId="1AEZqVMFTv9qTVp7QVA", useDomainAdminAccess=True).execute())`?

When I saw the official document of `useDomainAdminAccess` of "Method: drives.get", it says as follows.

> Issue the request as a domain administrator; if set to true, then the requester will be granted access if they are an administrator of the domain to which the shared drive belongs.

I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, how about removing it as follows?

#### From:

```
folder = (drive_api_service.drives()
  .get(driveId="1AEZqVMFTv9qTVp7QVA", useDomainAdminAccess=True)  
  .execute())
```

#### To:

```
folder = (drive_api_service.drives()
  .get(driveId="1AEZqVMFTv9qTVp7QVA")
  .execute())
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: drives.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/drives/get?apix_params=%7B%22driveId%22%3A%220AOdjQusSeJZJUk9PVA%22%7D)

Comment: That was exactly it. I needed to remove the useDomainAdminAccess=True!